# Stop Blinking of TextView

Tags: android

This is a code for blinking textview on a button click..

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    recordShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(1000); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    recordShow.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

i have to stop blinking on another button click...what to do..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes you want to stop the blink by clicking the same button. If you want to stop the click using a different button, you can split the if-else in the `onClick()` below into separate click handlers.

First, move `anim` outside `onClick()` and make it a field of the containing class. You need `anim` to be stored somewhere so you can cancel it later.

```
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f)
anim.setDuration(1000); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Second, create a boolean field in the containing class to keep track of whether the `TextView` is currently blinking:

```
boolean mBlinking = false;
```

Then:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    recordShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(!mBlinking){
        recordShow.startAnimation(anim);
        mBlinking = true;
    } else{
        recordShow.clearAnimation(anim); // cancel blink animation
        recordShow.setAlpha(1.0f); // restore original alpha
        mBlinking = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach could be:

**1.** Declare the **Animation** and **TextView** objects globally (outside any methods) in your Activity.

```
private Animation mAnim;
private TextView mRecordShow;
```

**2.** Setup a class that sets your animation properties and starts it. Let this class expect a **TextView** widget as its parameter.

```
protected void setBlinkingText(TextView textView) {
    mAnim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    mAnim.setDuration(1000); // Time of the blink
    mAnim.setStartOffset(20);
    mAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    textView.startAnimation(mAnim);
}
```

**3.** Setup another class that stops your animation on a given text view. Let this class expect a **TextView** widget as its parameter as well.

```
protected void removeBlinkingText(TextView textView) {
        textView.clearAnimation();
}
```

**4.** Now you can use your classes wherever desired, passing it the appropriate text views.

**e.g.**

***(a)*** In your `onClick()` method where you want to start the animation, replace all your animation code with:

```
setBlinkingText(mRecordShow);
```

***(b)*** wherever you want to stop the animation on that text view, just call:

```
removeBlinkingText(mRecordShow);
```